# How can you combine two regular expressions in one pattern with Pipe in Angular 8?

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I have angular 8 application and I want to validat for correct youtube url and vimeo url with pattern. Or Pipe?

So I have this:

```
        <ng-container *ngIf="is('VideoDisplay')">
          <iframe
            *ngIf="videoUrl.value"
            class="video-iframe"
            type="text/html"
            [src]="getVideoSafeUrl(videoUrl.value)"
            frameborder="0"
            allowfullscreen
          ></iframe>
          <mat-form-field>
            <input
              matInput
              type="url"
              name="videoUrl"
              ngModel
              #videoUrl="ngModel"
              placeholder="Url of video"
              i18n-placeholder
              pattern="^(http(s)?:\/\/)?((w){3}.)?youtu(be|.be)?(\.com)?\/.+"
              required
            />
            <mat-error>
               <app-element-edit-field-error
                [errors]="videoUrl.errors"
              ></app-element-edit-field-error>
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </ng-container>
```

But this is only validates for youtube. But I also want to combine it with Vimeo movies. So I have this regular expression for vimeo:

```
 var re = /\/\/(?:www\.)?vimeo.com\/([0-9a-z\-_]+)/i;
```

But how to combine this two now? And use it with a Pipe? So that you can use it in every template?

Thank you

So I created a pipe like this:

```
export class VideoUrlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {

    const vimeoReg = new RegExp(/\/\/(?:www\.)?vimeo.com\/([0-9a-z\-_]+)/i);
    const youtubeReg =  ^(http(s)?:\/\/)?((w){3}.)?youtu(be|.be)?(\.com)?\/.+;
    return null;
  }

}
```

I have it now like this:

```
export class RegexConstants {

  static readonly videoUrlsRegexConstant =
  /((http(s)?:\/\/)?((w){3}.)?youtu(be|.be)?(\.com)?\/.+)|(\/\/(?:www\.)?vimeo.com\/([0-9a-z\-_]+))/g;

}
```

Comment: my suggestion would be put the regular expression as a configuration file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You am combine the two regex.
Final regex

```
re = /((http(s)?:\/\/)?((w){3}.)?youtu(be|.be)?(\.com)?\/.+)|(\/\/(?:www\.)?vimeo.com\/([0-9a-z\-_]+))/g
```

For reusing this in every template, you can make a constants file and keep this variable there. Then just import it where you want to use it. No need of pipe there.

```
export class regexConstants {
    static readonly videoUrlsRegexConstant = /((http(s)?:\/\/)?((w){3}.)?youtu(be|.be)? 
           (\.com)?\/.+)|(\/\/(?:www\.)?vimeo.com\/([0-9a-z\-_]+))/g;
    ....
    ....
    ....
}
```

You can define other regex also in this file and reuse it everywhere in your application.

```
import {regexConstants} from 'path/to/regexConstants';

re = regexConstants.videoUrlsRegexConstant;
```

html:

```
<mat-form-field>
<input
matInput
type="url"
name="videoUrl"
ngModel
#videoUrl="ngModel"
placeholder="Url of video"
i18n-placeholder
pattern="{{re}}"
required
/>
```

Comment: Thank you! but if I do this as url: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BSG5iHK9Scw I get error but it is valid youtube url

Comment: This url also matches with the regex. I checked on https://regex101.com/ .